# WPF: Using Grids

Tags: wpf

I created a grid and inside this grid it contains a *TextBlock*. When I maximize or adjust the size of the window the content of the *TextBlock* doesn't stay in the center of the *Grid*.

Tried to keep this as short as possible. :>

```
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="515">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Welcome! Use the functionalities below.</TextBlock>
    </Grid> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Color each grid's background differently and you'll see what's happening.  You are running to the WPF layout constraints which you'll clearly see by coloring each of the UIELEMENTs background color differently.

Comment: Cheers! I did what you told me: The background color of the grid does not update when resizing or maximizing the window, The grid of the Window itself updates the color as expected. Don't know what to do because there is no code in the <Grid> </Grid> of the window itself.

Comment: Here's an image. http://uploadffs.nl/images/2014/11/03/Untitledfa7fe.png

Comment: To see what's going on

Comment: Fixed it by changing this code: <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="515"> To this: <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">

Comment: Also, best not to use any hard-coded widths or heights.  Maybe add some padding to the `TextBlock` instead of giving the inner `Grid` a fixed `Height`, e.g., `Padding="11"`.

Comment: Ya, the coloring did the trick.  The inner-grid was aligning to TOP and LEFT.  WPF was correct.  Thanks for posting back solution.

Comment: One of the things you may consider, is to use Grid.Rows, however there definitely will be times when you need stacked grids.  It's just good to know how they behave.  I tend to keep all grids horizontal and verticals set to auto and allow the parent container to constrain.  Thing seem to work better that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grids, by default, auto expand. That is, they take up as much area as they are allowed. Your outer grid will take up the entire client area of the window while the inner grid will stick to the top left of the outer grid, just as you have coded it to. If you want the inner grid to be centered, then do something like

```
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="46" Width="515">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Welcome! Use the functionalities below.</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You don't even have to include the horizontal and vertical alignment as grids will automatically centre.

If you just want to centre the TextBlock ...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="46" Width="515">Welcome! Use the functionalities below.</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The text can be centred using the TextAlignment property.

I hope this helps